# How can I make a button do a second action when clicked again in Java?

Tags: java

```
    buttonOne = new JButton("Who are you?");
    buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            nameField.setText("Taha Sabra");
            ageField.setText("24 years old");
            buttonOne.setText("Clear Me!");
        }
    });
```

This is what happens when I click it the first time. Now once the button reads Clear Me!, I want to be able to click it again and clear the nameField and ageField. Thank you!

Comment: use button.setActionCommand and getActionCommand to do the job

Comment: Or check button.text before and after

Answer (score 1):

Keep a state variable (class field) that indicates whether or not the button has already been clicked:

```
private boolean hasBeenClicked = false;
```

Then change the logic of your `actionPerformed`:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if ( ! hasBeenClicked ) {
            nameField.setText("Taha Sabra");
            ageField.setText("24 years old");
            buttonOne.setText("Clear Me!");
        } else {
            // Clear the fields
            nameField.setText("");
            ageField.setText("");

            // Set the the text on the button to the original.
            buttonOne.setText("Who are you?");
        }
        hasBeenClicked = ! hasBeenClicked;
    }
```

That last operation means that if `hasBeenClicked` was `false`, it will become `true`, and if it was `true` it will become `false`. So you can repeat this again if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple boolean flag inside your ActionListener:

```
buttonOne = new JButton("Who are you?");
buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    boolean clicked = false;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (clicked) {
            nameField.setText("");
            ageField.setText("");
            buttonOne.setText("Clear me again!");
        } else {
            nameField.setText("Taha Sabra");
            ageField.setText("24 years old");
            buttonOne.setText("Clear Me!");
            clicked = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is all you want ot achieve, you can also use ternary operator:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    nameField.setText(nameField.getText().equals("") ? "Taha Sabra" : "");
    ageField.setText(ageField.getText().equals("") ? "24 years old" : "");
    buttonOne.setText(buttonOne.getText().equals("Clear Me!") ? "Who are you?" : "Clear Me!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) [instance variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) within your class  to toggle between the two actions.

```
boolean clicked = false;

...

buttonOne = new JButton("Who are you?");
buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (!clicked) {
          nameField.setText("Taha Sabra");
          ageField.setText("24 years old");
          buttonOne.setText("Clear Me!");
          clicked = true;
        } else {
          nameField.setText("");
          ageField.setText("");
          clicked = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Using a boolean outside the ActionListener won't work since variables accessed from inner classes have to be `final`.

Comment: @Marv you are correct, that's why I said used a class variable, If updated the answer to make this clearer

Comment: A class variable? Maybe you mean a field? `static` isn't needed.

Comment: @Marv that's correct, a field, property or member valable; something declared within the class rather than a method

Comment: Alright, because you'd usually call something a class variable when it's a `static` field and you don't want that here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I noticed if I do it that way vs the other answers, I am able to repeat the actions every time I click!